# PhoneGap on Android deviceready not working!

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I'm working on a mobile application using phoneGap. I'm showing **deviceInfo** and and it's not working on Android emulator! but works on BlackBerry emulator. I`m using Dreamweaver cs 5.5. Any solution to this issue?

Here is my code:

```
 // invoked when device is ready 
    function deviceInfo() {
        document.getElementById('window.device.platform').innerHTML = 'window.device.platform = ' + window.device.platform;
        document.getElementById('window.device.version').innerHTML  = 'window.device.version  = ' + window.device.version;
        document.getElementById('window.device.uuid').innerHTML     = 'window.device.uuid     = ' + window.device.uuid;
        document.getElementById('window.device.phonegap').innerHTML = 'window.device.phonegap = ' + window.device.phonegap;

        navigator.network.isReachable("phonegap.com", function(reachability) {
            var states = {};
            states[NetworkStatus.NOT_REACHABLE]                      = 'No network connection';
            states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_CARRIER_DATA_NETWORK] = 'Carrier data connection';
            states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_WIFI_NETWORK]         = 'WiFi connection';
            document.getElementById('networkStatus').innerHTML = 'isReachable = ' + states[reachability];
        }, 
        { isIpAddress: false });        
    }       

    // invoked when application is resumed (brought to foregroud)
    function doResume() {
        console.log('doResume()');
    }

    // invoked when application is paused (sent to background)
    function doPause() {
        console.log('doPause()');
    }

    // register PhoneGap event listeners when DOM content loaded
    function init() {
        console.log('init()');
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceInfo, true); 
        document.addEventListener("resume", doResume, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", doPause, false);
    }

    function unload() {
        console.log('unload()'); 
    }

    function fail(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert(error, null, "Error");
    }
```

On my HTML:`<body onload="init()" onunload="unload()">`

Comment: Your JavaScript runs ok for me on the Android 2.2 emulator. Perhaps you should show enough of your HTML to reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is weired! it's not working on mine. Are you running your emulator through Dreamweaver?

Comment: I'm running the emulator from the ADT. I don't have Dreamweaver.

Comment: That was fast, by mean ADT you are running on eclipse? Sorry if I'm asking stupid question, I'm new to mobile development.

Comment: Just happened to be on when you asked. :-) Yes the ADT is the Android Development Tools plugin to Eclipse.

Comment: Thanx man, works on eclipse! But I have one issue, How do I set the resolution on the emulator? For some reason everything shrinks in the emulator.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the name of the cordova script is spelled correctly: 
it may read

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.x.x.js"></script>
```

where it should read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: The 1.x.x should be based on the name of the .js in ...assets/www As of this writing, the 1.5.0 is correct, but check the js file used when setting up the project.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />"` is present in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: This resolved my problem aside from doing what this other post suggested: http://www.philliprhodes.com/content/phonegap-deviceready-not-called-android

Answer (score 1):

I could get rid of this issue when I found out, that the cordova version numbers of my cordova.js and the cordova.jar file didn't match.

Getting both from the same cordova version fixed it for me.
That was a time consuming and stupid mistake on muy side.